# Gridview - Use first row of returned data as header

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview, header

This is so obvious that I hate to ask, and the only similar question I can find on StackOverflow has a -2 rating. But I can't figure it out, so here goes:

My codebehind (C#) gets data from an Excel spreadsheet and stores it in a DataSet. My gridivew uses the DataSet as a DataSource. Works fine, but my header names are just "F1", "F2"....

Can I set the first row of data as my gridview header? I can't hard-code my headers because the format of the Excel file can change, and I can't control that. What I need is for my first row of data to appear as the gridview header.

Any help? I can post some of my code if necessary, but this seems like pretty generic question.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want first `row` as header or you want column names as header ?

Comment: I want the first row returned by my SQL query to be the column header names. The first row of my users' spreadsheets contains the column names, and those are the column names I want on my gridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the headers of grid view just use

```
gridview1.Columns[Index].HeaderText = "Text";
```

If you want to set your first row as headers, then just take the first row from the datatable and set it corresponding headers.

```
gridview1.Columns[Index].HeaderText = dataTable.Rows[0]["ColumnName"].ToString();
```

*You can also loop the datatable columns if you don't want to specify explicitly.

Comment: Hey, that's a good idea. I already knew how to hard-code headers, but that won't work for my application. But I hadn't thought of looping. I'll try it, thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can loop columns like foreach (DataColumn col in dataTable.Columns)